# Sum across select row and multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I haave a table like so:

| Shop | 01/03 | 02/03 | 03/03 | 04/03 | 05/03 | 06/03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shop A | 400 | 40 | 300 | 100 | 50 | 10 |
| shop b | 300 | 30 | 400 | 10 | 50 | 20 |
| shop c | 200 | 20 | 100 | 10 | 70 | 30 |

how do i get the total for shop B between 04/03 and 06/03 so 80 or shop a between 01/03 and 04/03 so 840. I tried a sumifs but that seems to only be able to select across the table not able to select a specific row.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:G4*(A2:A4=L2)*(B1:G1>=J2)*(B1:G1<=K2))
```

In `B1:G1` should be real dates.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You got an answer I'd prefer too using `SUMPRODUCT()`, but just for the record; you can use `SUMIFS()` in this case and just feed it the right row:

[image]

Formula in `L2`:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(B2:G4,MATCH(K2,A2:A4,0),0),B1:G1,">="&I2,B1:G1,"<="&J2)
```

Though a little bit more verbose, it's not that resource heavy.